# Requested 'gl >= 9.2.0' but version of GL is 1.2 xorg-server

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

Today I tried build and install xorg-server v 1.19.3. I am using a very old driver and have to install this version for everything to work.

When I used **./Configure**, I got this error:

```
configure:27189: checking for GL
configure:27196: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$GLPROTO $LIBGL"
Requested 'gl >= 9.2.0' but version of GL is 1.2
configure:27199: $? = 1
configure:27213: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$GLPROTO $LIBGL"
Requested 'gl >= 9.2.0' but version of GL is 1.2
configure:27216: $? = 1
configure:27230: result: no
Requested 'gl >= 9.2.0' but version of GL is 1.2
configure:27246: error: Package requirements (glproto >= 1.4.17 gl >= 9.2.0) were not met:

Requested 'gl >= 9.2.0' but version of GL is 1.2

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GL_CFLAGS
and GL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

*I copied this from .log file*

Can anyone help me?

Comment: »»Package requirements (glproto >= 1.4.17 «« : *Package* config file *glproto.pc* is provided by `x11proto-dev` → → `/usr/share/pkgconfig/glproto.pc` ...... And *gl.pc* : `libgl1-mesa-dev` → → `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc` ............. On-line search page https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=glproto.pc

Comment: I removed this files. Removed (--purge) modules. Install modules. But the error remained. so i go to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc and change version to 9.2.0... it works.

Comment: fix by:
```
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/merge_requests/292/diffs#87db583be5c13c1f7b3c958b10e03d67b6a2ca06_763_763
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/merge_requests/292/diffs#87db583be5c13c1f7b3c958b10e03d67b6a2ca06_1118_1118
```